# Iterate through DIVS showing/hiding them in a carousel style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/X763j/

What I am trying to do is loop through them showing one at a time in a kinda infinite slider way.

JavaScript is not my strong point, but from my understanding you can use the jQuery .toggle function.

How would I do it so that it only showed the next one.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with jQUery. Hide the `:visible` one and show the `.next()` one. Once you get to the end, the next one is the `:first` one.

```
function next() {
    var current = $("#slider .slide:visible");
    current.hide();
    var next = current.next(".slide");
    if(next.length == 0)
        next = current.siblings().filter(":first")
    console.log(next);
    next.show();
}

setInterval(next, 1000);​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X763j/2/)

You can check the [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) to get more information on all of the functions and selectors I used.

You should take a look at one of the many [jQuery Carousel](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55) plugins too.

Comment: Nice use of :visible selector! BTW next.length will return true or false depending on the value, so no need to compare it to an integer.

Comment: Thank you! Excatly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

With setInterval you can call a function that handles the sliders for you, something like this.

```
setInterval(slide, 4000); // Set interval, callback function, and how often to swap slide

function slide() {
$('div.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(500, function() {
    if($(this).next('div.slide').length) {
        $(this).next('div.slide').addClass('active').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('div.slide').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn(500);
    }

});
}​
```

A jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/X763j/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another code example to just loop your slides. Note that this is not optimized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var slides = $('.slide');  
    var currentSlide = slides.first();        
    slides.each(function(index, value) { //Hide the all the slides
        $(value).hide();
    });

    currentSlide.show() //Show the first

    setInterval(function() { //Interval that loops.
          i++;
          if (i + 1 > slides.length) i = 0;
          currentSlide.hide();
          currentSlide = slides.eq(i);
          currentSlide.show();      
    }, 3000);
});​
```